# Tank game movement

Tags: java, graphics

I am making a `tank` game like the `Atari tank game` and I ran into some troubles. I'm trying to make the `enemy's tank move towards the player's tank` but it `can't move diagonally` since the player isn't allowed to do that also. However, the way I implemented it, it goes diagonally when the distance from the x and y axis are equal to each other. Is there a way I can make it so that it would be forced go in one direction for a while after changing direction? The way do it is that it will `compare its x and y values` with the player's tank ( the tank that is being passed in ) and the four cases are for if the `x-component is bigger than y` and is it on the`right or left`, and if the `y-component is bigger than x`and is it `above or below` the player's tank. Thank you for the help!

```
public void enemyMove(Tank t) {
    if ( Math.abs(getX() - t.getX()) >= Math.abs(getY() - t.getY()) && getX() > t.getX() )
      goLeft();
    else if ( Math.abs(getX() - t.getX()) > Math.abs(getY() - t.getY()) && getX() < t.getX() )
      goRight();
    else if ( Math.abs(getX() - t.getX()) <= Math.abs(getY() - t.getY()) && getY() > t.getY() )
      goUp();
    else if ( Math.abs(getX() - t.getX()) < Math.abs(getY() - t.getY()) && getY() < t.getY() )
      goDown();

    setX(getX() + dx);
    setY(getY() + dy);
  }

public void goUp() {
    dx = 0;
    dy = -1;
  }

public void goDown() {
    dx = 0;
    dy = 1;
  }

public void goLeft() {
    dx = -1;
    dy = 0;
  }

public void goRight() {
    dx = 1;
    dy = 0;
  }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe you need to use sleep or timer to pause the game for a few ticks. Perhaps the tank moves left, and then immediately after moves down so that to the human it it looks diagonal.

Comment: Yeah I know that's what happening so I want to prevent it from happening. I want to make it so that , say, if I goes left, it will go left for a while before changing to another direction. And if you pause the game, wouldn't it also affect the player and makes the game seems laggy?

Comment: not pause the game per say.

Use the built in java timer and set it to, say , 40 ticks a second. Then, the player and the tank will move once every 3 ticks or something.

At this rate, the human eye will be able to process the movements very easily.

Comment: If the distance is equal, either randomly choose a direction or choose an arbitrary value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is a little gross, but should do what you want.  In your current code the enemy is moving one pixel in the X direction in the first frame, then one pixel in the Y direction in the next frame, which makes the movement look diagonal.  The code below sets a short-term target point for the enemy tank to head towards in either the X or Y direction, at some distance away defined by MOVE_BLOCK.  The enemy will move until it passes that target point, then recalculate which direction it should be moving.  Note that enemyMove will be called every time a new frame is created, so probably 60 times a second.

```
// The tank will move this distance in x or y before changing directions
private final int MOVE_BLOCK = 120;
// The short-term target of the enemy tank
Point target = null;
public void enemyMove(Tank t) {
    /* true if enemy is moving left and enemy is already left of target point, 
     * or moving right and right of target... */
    boolean passedTarget = target == null || 
        (dx < 0 && getX() < target.getX()) ||
        (dx > 0 && getX() > target.getX()) ||
        (dy < 0 && getY() < target.getY()) ||
        (dy > 0 && getY() > target.getY());
    // Calculate a new target point if the old target was passed
    if(passedTarget) {
        int xDist = Math.abs(getX() - t.getX());
        int yDist = Math.abs(getY() - t.getY());
        if ( xDist > yDist ) {
            // Cover the remaining distance when close to the target
            int moveLength = xDist < MOVE_BLOCK ? xDist : MOVE_BLOCK;
            if( getX() >= t.getX() )
                goLeft();
                target = new Point(getX() - moveLength, getY());
            else
                goRight();
                target = new Point(getX() + moveLength, getY());
        } else {
            int moveLength = yDist < MOVE_BLOCK ? yDist : MOVE_BLOCK;
            if ( getY() >= t.getY() ) {
                goUp();
                target = new Point(getX(), getY() - moveLength);
            } else {
                goDown();
                target = new Point(getX(), getY() + moveLength);
            }
        }
    }

    setX(getX() + dx);
    setY(getY() + dy);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I was just asking for suggestions but this is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Manhattan distance and find the median then move the tank in both directions.